# How can I get negative radius Android Round Corner with XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, shapes

I need to get the below shape in Android I can't get this as using Constraint layout, refer my code.

```
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/theme_dark"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="500dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[sample i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QnWn.png)

Comment: Consider to use an Image such us a `PNG` or better a `SVG` image to manage it

Answer (score 0):

Try this drawable xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-200dp"
        android:top="-400dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/purple_500"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Output for above drawable is:**

- If set background to half part of screen:

[image]

- If set background to full screen:

[image]